# Elements with display set to none are shown

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have created the following Greasemonkey script for Firefox to help filter class names in the long list of [Java API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        JDK API Doc helper problematic
// @version     1
// @namespace   Xolve
// @description Provides in place search for JDK API docs
// @include     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/*
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

var classNamesFrame;
var classNamesDoc;
var classNamesHash = {};
var timeoutId;

function textBoxTextChanged(ev)
{
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    console.log(ev.target.value);
    // For case insensitive comparision
    var query = String(ev.target.value).trim().toLowerCase();
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(filterClassNames, 600, query);

}

function filterClassNames(query)
{
    if(query.length == 0) {
        for(k in classNamesHash) {
            classNamesHash[k].style.display = "";
        }
        return;
    }
    for(k in classNamesHash) {
        if(k.startsWith(query)) {
            console.log("setting to display: " + k);
            classNamesHash[k].style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            classNamesHash[k].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function init()
{
    // Find list of class names
    classNamesDoc = classNamesFrame.contentDocument;
    classNamesATags = classNamesDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i = 0; i < classNamesATags.length; i++) {
        // For case insensitive comparision
        classNamesHash[classNamesATags[i].textContent.toLowerCase()] = classNamesATags[i];
    }

    // Add a text box
    var textBox = classNamesDoc.createElement("input");
    var body = classNamesDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var classListNode = body.getElementsByClassName("indexContainer")[0];
    body.insertBefore(textBox, classListNode);
    textBox.addEventListener("keyup", textBoxTextChanged);
}

classNamesFrame = document.getElementsByName("packageFrame")[0];
classNamesFrame.onload = init;
```

**This is what this script does**

1. Add a text box to the frame which lists class names. Call is query box.
2. Create a hash of all class names (converted to lower case) to the corresponding DOM element.
3. When a user enters first few characters of the class name in query box, it loops through the hash keys and sets display property of matching elements to "block" and display property of non-matching element to "none"

**Problem**

Some elements are always displayed e.g. AclEntry, Array etc. irrespective of contents of query box,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are multiple "AclEntry" links, for example. So, when you first add the elements to your `classNamesHash` array, it will overwrite the 1st "AclEntry" link with the 2nd one because the id you're using is the same.

You need to append something unique to this id and then since you're only checking `.startsWith` to match it should still work just fine.

For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < classNamesATags.length; i++) {
    // For case insensitive comparision
    classNamesHash[classNamesATags[i].textContent.toLowerCase() + '_' + i] = classNamesATags[i];
}
```

This will append _# to the end of the id inside the array and should keep them unique so you will have `AclEntry_34` and `AclEntry_35` or something like that.  When you try to filter out Acl* it will match both of them.

Conversely, **all** the links will now be in the `classNamesHash` object, so that *all* unmatching links can be hidden.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it seem less tentative, since it is correct and I'm wondering why the OP didn't see that.  Roll it back if you don't like the change.